# having problem in ms access login form vba,

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Try to create login form with security level, so that some users can only see reports and some can add/edit record as well.

getting Qualifier must be collection error

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
Dim FRM As Integer
Dim Reports As Integer



FRM = DLookup("Forms", "User_Account", "UserName='" & Me.UserName & "'")
Reports = DLookup("Reports", "User_Account", "UserName='" & Me.UserName & "'")


' ~~~ Execution ~~~~~

If IsNull(Me.UserName) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the correct User Name!", vbCritical, "Denied"
    Me.UserName.SetFocus

ElseIf IsNull(Me.Password) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the correct Password!", vbCritical, "Denied"
    Me.TxtPassword.SetFocus


Else
    If (IsNull(DLookup("UserName", "User_Account", "UserName='" & Me.UserName & "'"))) Or _
    IsNull(DLookup("Password", "User_Account", "Password='" & Me.TxtPassword & "'")) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the correct Username and Password!", vbCritical, "Denied"
    Me.UserName = ""
    Me.TxtPassword = ""
    Me.UserName.SetFocus
    
Else
    If DLookup("Password", "User_Account", "UserName='" & Me.UserName & "'") <> Me.TxtPassword Then
    MsgBox "Incorrect Username or Password!", vbCritical, "Denied"
    Me.UserName = ""
    Me.TxtPassword = ""
    Me.UserName.SetFocus
    
Else
    If FRM = -1 Or Reports = -1 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigation Form"
    
    
    If FRM = -1 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigation Form"
    FRM![Navigation Form]!Forms.Enabled = True
    End If
    
    If Reports = -1 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigation Form"
    Reports![Navigation Form]!Reports.Enabled = True
    End If
    
    
    
    
Else
    MsgBox "You do not have permission" & vbCrLf & vbcrld & _
    "Please contact Database Administrator", vbInformation, "Denied"
    
    


End If
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `FRM![Navigation Form]` won't work if `FRM` is an number...  It does have any properties or methods.  Assuming that's the problem line - you don't mention the location in your post...

Comment: FRM and Reports are declared locally as integers.  So they both default to 0.  The local FRM and Reports block and global public or Property version of themselves.  the Local FRM and Reports are never changed hence they always = 0 and all your tests fail.  Also I'd be surprised if your if else structure is working properly.  Use if, elseif, elseif, ..., elseif, else, endif.